# How to use the ng-repeat filter with a variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am currently working on a search bar that will allow the user to search for different projects in out database.

```
<div class="col-md-6 project-info" ng-if="vm.done && !vm.printFriendlyView" ng-repeat="project in vm.filteredprojects |filter: {title: searchText } | filter:project.status = 'Active'">
```

As of right now, if I put a static value (example: 'Super Project') in the filter I will only a the project with that name. However I also made a variable that uses ng-change in a textfield to update (the variable name is searchText and it is initialized in the model as $scope.searchText).
However, I cannot get this variable to work for some reason. I would like to know if I am using the filter the wrong way?

Any sort of help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Wouldn't it be `vm.searchText` as you're using the scope as sytax?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you filter your status field wrong, because you use = you assign it. I would change it to

```
<div class="col-md-6 project-info" ng-if="vm.done && !vm.printFriendlyView"
              ng-repeat="project in vm.filteredprojects | filter: {title: searchText } | filter: {status: 'Active'}">
```

Also I would not keep ng-if and ng-repeat in the same element, because they are both structural directives.